# Volumes of the solid of revolution around y axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The body which regards to the functions $\left\{0\le y\le x^{-2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),\:x\in \left(0,1\right)\right\}$ is given. Please calculate the volume of the revolution of it around the y axis.

Now, I fully understand that
0 $\le x^{-2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ iff $\frac{1}{\pi +2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}\le \:x\le \frac{1}{2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}$.
Hence, the integral should be:
$2\cdot \:\pi \int _{\frac{1}{\pi +2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}}^{\frac{1}{2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}}x^{-1}\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$ . It seems that the integral converges.

How can I solve it? Am I on the correct way?

**EDIT=** I think I need to find a function g(x) that bounds f(x) from above and converges.

**EDIT #2=** after changing the argument [1/x=t] I got this thing. $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\int _{2\pi n}^{2\pi n+\pi }\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}$ Can anyone solve it?

Much obliged,

Comment: Is this volume, or surface area? The integral looks wrong either way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its volume.

Comment: I find $\int^{1/(2\pi n)}_{1/(\pi+2\pi n)} f(x)\,dx$ more legible than $\int _{\frac{1}{\pi +2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}}^{\frac{1}{2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}} f(x)\,dx$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh sorry got confused a little.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the best method here is the shell method.

In the shell method, since you are rotating the function about the y-axis, you have to set your function in terms of y, which is already given to you.

Your integral will then become: $$2\pi \int_{\frac{1}{\pi +2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}}^{\frac{1}{2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}}x^{-1}\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$

Now you solve using integration by parts.

Make $u = 1/x$, and $dv = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

**EDIT** It doesn't seem that this integral can be solved using IBP.

take a look at this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%281%2Fx%29*%28sin%281%2Fx%29%29

And this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html

Comment: Note that y must be positive, and $x^{-2}sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is not always positive when $x\in \left(0,1\right)$ unless $\frac{1}{\pi +2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}\le \:x\le \frac{1}{2\cdot \:\pi \cdot \:n}$

Comment: I realized that your method is correct, you are simply looking for a way to solve

Comment: I have provided a solution

Comment: I still dont understand how can you use the volume of the whole solid between 0 to 1 when some of it shouldn't be counted.

Comment: is your method wrong. As you said earlier, y cannot be negative, so it must be between a specific interval of x values

Comment: Well, I used the same formula as you did. $\:x^{-1}\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ cannot be integrated elementarily so I cannot integrate it by parts.